# Responsive design issues on Blackberry

Tags: mobile, blackberry, responsive-design, viewport

Note: the following issues are applicable only to blackberry - all other devices tested (multiple android models and iPhone OS) are not being affected by these issues.

**Problem #1**: Horizontal scrolling

I have the following meta tags in the head:

```html
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, user-scalable=no" />
```

However, I'm still getting a huge side scroll - about twice the width of the page. I have overflow-x: hidden on the body and it's still scrolling regardless.

**Problem #2**: List floating issues

My navigation is comprised of an unordered list of links. I have the following css applied:

```css
div#masthead nav ul li {
    background: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

div#masthead nav ul li a {
    font-size: .9em;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

The width: auto is causing some problems on the blackberry. The links are stacking strangely: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0PXz.jpg (screenshot: top is how it looks on other phones, bottom is on the blackberry - please ignore the add this bar)

If I set a fixed pixel width on the li it solves the wrapping issue, but then doesn't give me a consistent margin-right after each list element.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to horizontal scrolling:

I've just included a width: 100% on the body as well and this solved the horizontal scrolling issue.

Problem #2 still remains unsolved.